# get attributes data from xml between keys (fromid=1 toid=3) in php

Tags: php, xml, between

i got this xml file: (items.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<items>
...
    <item id="1546" article="a" name="item 1546 name">
        <attribute key="weight" value="12000" />
        <attribute key="slotType" value="two-handed" />
        <attribute key="itemType" value="distance" />
        <attribute key="range" value="5" />
        <attribute key="hitChance" value="1" />
        <attribute key="attack" value="3" />
    </item>
...
    <item id="4355" article="an" name="item 4355 name">
        <attribute key="weight" value="19000" />
        <attribute key="itemType" value="distance" />
        <attribute key="range" value="5" />
        <attribute key="hitChance" value="4" />
        <attribute key="attack" value="9" />
    </item>
...
    <item fromid="6788" toid="6790" article="a" name="item 6788 or 6789 or 6790 name">
        <attribute key="weight" value="1600" />
    </item>
</items>
```

and my scripts are all done already using the key `id` but some tags doesn't have the key `id`, but the `fromid` and `toid` keys instead...

here is my codes:

```
$c_item_reader = new XMLReader();
if (!$c_item_reader->open($config['site']['server_path'].'data/items/items.xml')) {
    die("Failed to open 'items.xml'");
}
$item_fromdb = "1546 => 1, 6789 => 3";
$f_item = array();
$f_bits = explode(",",$item_fromdb);
foreach ($f_bits as $b) {
    $b = str_replace('"', '', $b);
    $bobs = explode(" => ", $b);
    $f_item[$bobs[0]] = $bobs[1];
}
while($c_item_reader->read()) {
    if ($c_item_reader->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT && $c_item_reader->name == 'item') {
        $id = $c_item_reader->getAttribute('id');
        $fromid = $c_item_reader->getAttribute('fromid');
        $toid = $c_item_reader->getAttribute('toid');
        $name = $c_item_reader->getAttribute('name');
        $item = $c_item_reader->expand();
        $attributes = array();
        foreach($item->childNodes as $attribute) {
            if(get_class($attribute) != 'DOMElement') continue;
            $attributes[] = (string) '"'.$attribute->getAttribute('key').'" => "'.$attribute->getAttribute('value').'"';
        }
        $ff_dsds = implode(",",$attributes);
        foreach($f_item as $f_itemid => $f_itemamount){
            if($id == $f_itemid){
                $f_item_attr = array();
                $f_bits_attr = explode(",",$ff_dsds);
                foreach ($f_bits_attr as $b2) {
                    $b2 = str_replace('"', '', $b2);
                    $bobs2 = explode(" => ", $b2);
                    $f_item_attr[$bobs2[0]] = $bobs2[1];
                }
                foreach($f_item_attr as $f_attr_name => $f_attr_value){
                    if($l_attr_id == "weight")
                        $y_weight = $f_attr_value;
                    [...]
                }
                if($y_weight)
                    $f_weight = number_format($y_weight / 100, 2, '.', '');
                echo $f_itemamount.'-'.$id.' => "weighs '.$f_weight.'", ';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

here is the print result I'm trying to get:

```
1-1546 => "weighs 120.00", 3-6789 => "weighs 16.00",
```

Comment: should I use somehow this: `if(!$id){ $id = $fromid }`? how would I get the value between fromid and toid? anyone?